# My drop down list is not visible in navbar

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, navbar

I created a navbar with hover drop down list.
Below that I created series of images display using javascript.
When I hover on the navbar the drop down is working perfect but the list is going behind the images.
How to display the drop down list on the images?
Thanks.

Comment: What does your attempt look like?

Comment: I am trying to design my webpage look like this website homepage. [linl](http://www.astcorporation.com/index.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

set z-index property to 10 for your drop down list